# What is the reason for error message "(" was unexpected at this time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip

I am writing a simple batch script to just ping a ton of IPs to see if they are online. I wrote some code and every time I run it, I get an error saying

> ( was unexpected at this time.

I'm not sure where I went wrong. So if somebody could just tell me what to do instead that would be great. I'm kind of new to batch so my code isn't the greatest.

```
::@echo off
color b
title Get Online IPs
for /L %%A IN (0,1,255) do (
    for /L %%B IN (0,1,255) do (
        for /L %%C IN (0,1,255) do (
            for /L %%D IN (0,1,255) do (
                set %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D = IP
                ping -n 1 %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D > ./iptemp.txt
                for /F "delims=" %%i in (iptemp.txt) do set "iptemp=%%i"
                if %iptemp% == "Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss)," (
                    echo IP offline
                    goto skip
                )
                echo %IP% >> IPlist.txt
                echo %IP% is online!
                :skip
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to ping the entire IPv4 address range, i.e. ping all IPv4 addresses of the world. Do you know that you try to ping 4 294 967 296 addresses?

The line `set %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D = IP` is completely wrong. The name of the variable and the string value to assign to the variable are on wrong side of the equal sign. And take at look on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for an explanation why there should be no spaces around the equal sign.

Delayed environment variable expansion is needed whenever a variable is defined or modified within a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` and the value of the variable is referenced in same command block. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read all output help pages for details about delayed expansion as used in the code below.

Windows command processor does not support labels within a **FOR** loop. The solution here is using **IF** with **ELSE**.

The **IF** condition could be never true as compared is a string with no double quotes with a string with double quotes. The surrounding double quotes are needed here for the string comparison, but they are not removed by command **IF** from the compared strings.

The **IF** condition for string comparison is also the reason for the syntax error because environment variable `iptemp` is not defined above first **FOR** and is therefore undefined on parsing the command block. This results in replacing `%iptemp%` already before most outer **FOR** being first time executed by nothing resulting in the line

```
if  == "Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100 loss)," (
```

And this line is of course completely wrong. Note: Single percent sign is also removed.

The percent sign in the string to compare must be escaped with one more percent sign to be interpreted as literal character and not as beginning of a variable reference.

In code below in last **ECHO** line the exclamation mark must be escaped with `^^` to be interpreted as literal character because of delayed expansion being enabled which changes meaning of `!` from a simple literal character to delimiter of a variable name whose value should be referenced without expansion on parsing the command block.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color b
title Get Online IPs
set "ListFile=IPlist.txt"
if exist "%ListFile%" del "%ListFile%"
for /L %%A in (0,1,255) do (
    for /L %%B in (0,1,255) do (
        for /L %%C in (0,1,255) do (
            for /L %%D in (0,1,255) do (
                set "IP=%%A.%%B.%%C.%%D"
                for /F "delims=" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 !IP!') do set "iptemp=%%i"
                if "!iptemp!" == "Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100%% loss)," (
                    echo !IP! is offline.
                ) else (
                    echo !IP! is online^^!>>"%ListFile%"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

On my German Windows the string comparison is never true and therefore all IPs are "online" which of course is wrong.

Much better would be using exit code of console application **PING** which is 0 on successful pinging and 1 on error. The exit code of previously executed command or console application can be evaluated with `if errorlevel X` respectively `if not errorlevel X` depending on checking exit code (errorlevel) for greater or equal `X` or lower than `X`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color b
title Get Online IPs
set "ListFile=IPlist.txt"
if exist "%ListFile%" del "%ListFile%"
for /L %%A in (0,1,255) do (
    for /L %%B in (0,1,255) do (
        for /L %%C in (0,1,255) do (
            for /L %%D in (0,1,255) do (
                set "IP=%%A.%%B.%%C.%%D"
                %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 !IP! >nul
                if errorlevel 1 (
                    echo !IP! is offline.
                ) else (
                    echo !IP! is online^^!>>"%ListFile%"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `color /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ping /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `title /?`

Read also the Microsoft articles:

- [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /L %%A IN (0,1,255) do (
    for /L %%B IN (0,1,255) do (
        for /L %%C IN (0,1,255) do (
            for /L %%D IN (0,1,255) do (
             set "flag="
             for /F "delims=" %%i in ('ping -n 1 %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D') do (
              if "%%i" == "Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss)," set flag=Y
             )
             if defined flag (
              echo %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D offline
             ) else (
              echo %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D >> IPlist.txt
              echo %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D  is online!
             )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

{untested}

```
set %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D = IP
```

Will set environment variables 0.0.0.0<kbd>Space</kbd> .. 255.255.255.255<kbd>Space</kbd> to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>IP"
Spaces are significant on **both** sides of the `=` operator in a standard `set` statement - and you can't simply reverse the syntax and expect `cmd` to work out what you mean.

```
  for /F "delims=" %%i in (iptemp.txt) do set "iptemp=%%i"
```

will set the value of `iptemp` to the contents of the last line of the file. It's unlikely to match the string you have chosen in the later test.

And you can't use a label within a "block statement" (parenthesised series of statements)

Furthermore, as is explained in thousands of SO responses, in order to access the run-time value of a variable within a block, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` mode and use `!var!`. (There are other ways - this is the simplest). `%var%` is **always** the value of the variable **when the block statement was encountered**

An this is the source of your error report - actually "( was **NOT** expected at this time". As `iptemp` is undefined when the block is encountered (and that block is the `for /L %%A ...` block), `cmd` interprets this line as

```
if == "Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss)," (
```

and can make no sense of it.

Your 'IP offline' report would say precisely that - 'IP offline' - not the IP address.

The revised (but **untested**) code uses `flag` as a sack of potatoes and initialises it to *empty* - the enclosing quotes ensure that any trailing spaces are **not** included in the value assigned to `flag`

The `for/f` delivers the entirity of each line of the `ping` output to `%%i` in turn, and then each line (now in `%%i`) is compared to your magic string (note that **both** sides need to be quoted) and `flag` is set to *something - anything will do* if the magic string matches *any* output line.

When the `for/f` finishes, the **current value** of `flag` is interpreted (note that `if defined` works on the **current** value, not the **initial** value) and one or other of the reports is generated.